# JQuery mouse events with stacked elements

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I have a web page with a table. Using jQuery 1.3.2, I absolutely position a div element over the top of each row on the table. The overlaying div has a higher z-index.

I attach 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' events to the overlaying div element. On mouseenter, I throw a red border around the overlaying div. On mouseleave, I remove the border. So the effect is to have each table row highlighted as the mouse moves over the table.

Everything works fine until the mouse enters some text in the table. Then the border turns off. So what seems to be happening is:

1. Enter overlaying div - mouseenter called
2. Enter table text (still within overlaying div) - mouseleave called on overlaying div.

I eventually want to capture the click event anywhere within the overlaying div to do something else, so I can't use CSS to handle this.

Here's the code:

```
    $('.overlay').bind("mouseenter", function() {
            $(this).css('border','solid 1px red');
        }
    )
    $('.overlay').bind("mouseleave", function() {
            $(this).css('border','none');
        }
    )
```

I'd appreciate any help on either getting the overlaying div to capture the mouse or getting the table to ignore it.

Comment: Do you have any floated elements contained within your DIV?  If so, it could very well be that you need to apply overflow: hidden to your DIV element as a hack to clear the floats.

Comment: No floats. Just an empty div covering the table row with the idea of making table rows mouse sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be an IE problem. Anyway, changing the div to a transparent img solved it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, mouseenter and mouseleave do not bubble down to child elements. (src: [Mouseenter and mouseleave events for Firefox](http://blog.stchur.com/2007/03/15/mouseenter-and-mouseleave-events-for-firefox-and-other-non-ie-browsers/)).

Try mouseover and mouseout instead and it should work as expected.

Edit:  By bubble down to child elements, I mean bubble up from child elements.

Comment: Unfortunately, the table is not a child of the overlay, so events don't bubble.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that.  The absolute positioning must have slipped my mind by the time I responded.  Did you give mouseover a chance though?  I can't see why it wouldn't work and mouseenter is non-standard anyways.

Comment: I got to thinking about this and wondered how you were even able to select the underlying text with a div overlaying it.  So I put together a test and the code you mentioned seems to be working fine (in Firefox at least, don't have an IE available to test with atm).  Maybe the problem is somewhere else in the code?  Or maybe, I'm still misinterpreting the problem?

Check it out.  http://jsbin.com/ozeta

Comment: Looks like an IE problem. Your solution works fine in Firefox but not IE. Thanks.